# C++ separating function for performance optimalization

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I want to separate two parts of my function to make it faster. In each two separated parts there are data which I want to use later (in the `//Do someting else.` part).

I thought of `std::thread` but it seemed to be slow because of it needs too much time to setting up. Then I tried `std::async` due to a suggestion and it was better then `std::thread` but still slower than the original code (without threading, just calling the funcions).

Example code:

```
Variables
    INT a, INT b

Part1
    a = 4 + 5
End of Part1

Part2
    b = 2 + 6
End of Part2

Main
    Loop (endless)
        call Part1
        call Part2
        print (a - b)
        call Loop
    End of Loop

End of Main
```

Of course there are a lot of thing to do in these two parts, that's just an example.

Comment: Are you asking how to restart the 2 threads?

Comment: Do you want the threads to restart on subsequent iterations?

Comment: [`join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) *blocks* until the thread is finished. If you want to do something in the loop except waiting for your threads then you need some other way to signal thread finished (for example an [atomic boolean variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) that you poll). Or use something like [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).

Comment: you cannot die twice.

Comment: It would help if you tell us what you want to accomplish exactly. As the other say, `join` will wait for the thread finished. You need to create it again, if you want to `join` again. But, one will have the question: why do you join at the first place? Creating a thread is an expensive operation.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood what `joinable()` and `join()` do. The threads you've created are joinable because they haven't been detached. Those calls to join will block until the corresponding thread finishes. There's no way to speed that up. Putting aside the coding details, what are you trying to do?

Comment: But yes, I want to restart the threads as fast as possible for using them in the next nun of the loop.

Comment: But if the threads are bad 'tools', could you suggest me someting that's fast enough? I just tried `std::async` but is there any faster thing?

Comment: Then use synchronization methods (like condition variables) to tell the thread what to do, and don't let the thread die. Join is a bad solution for this. Only destroy (join) the thread, when the full calculation is over.

Comment: I see. Then, I'm going to edit my question. Thank you, I learned very important things! :D

Comment: @geza -- yup. I should be more careful what I write this early in the morning.

Comment: about `std::async`: I would not recommend it, if you need a lot of async calls. Exact mechanics is not defined by the standard, so you cannot rely on its performance at all. If you need max. performance, `std::thread` is the way to go.

Comment: NagyDani: please read a tutorial about condition variables. For these kind of things, they are a possible tool. Basically, there are worker threads, and there is a manager thread (main). Worker threads are in a wait state (waiting on the condition variable). When the manager thread creates a job (to be done by a worker thread), then it signals the condition variable. Then the system wakes up one of the worker threads, and the thread does the job. When it finished, it could signal another condvar to make the manager thread know. Then it waits for another job via the first condvar.

Comment: And you should make jobs as big as possible. Synchronization has its cost, it is not free. If your jobs are very small, then you should go with some kind of lockless mechanism, like this: http://codesuppository.blogspot.hu/2009/01/jobswarm-microthreading-framework-with.html (I haven't tried it)

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder if I can reset them or 'make it joinable' again. Do you have any solutions?

`std::thread`'s are movable, so you can simply *"reassign"* them after the `join()` call:

```
t1 = std::thread{ThreadFunc1};
t2 = std::thread{ThreadFunc2};
```

---

Alternatively instead of joining at all, you may design your thread functions a bit differently and use a synchronization method of some kind. E.g. something alike:

```
std::mutex m1;
std::condition_variable cv1;
std::atomic<bool> stop1;

void ThreadFunc1() {
    while(!stop1) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m1);
            cv1.wait(lk);
        }
        // Do work ...
        cv1.notify_one();
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1{ThreadFunc1};

    while(true) {
       // Trigger thread to do work
       cv1.notify_one();

       // Wait for thread to get it's work done
       {
           std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m1);
           cv1.wait(lk);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reassignment takes too much time in my case sadly.

Comment: @NagyDani Takes too much time regarding to which particular constraint? Elaborate about that in your question please.

Comment: @NagyDani I have updated my answer with an alternative mechanism, that keeps the original thread alive.